# Multiple string values containment check in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to check for multiple string values containment in a variable, so far I know that I can check for a single string value containment in a variable but did not find anything on multiple values containment.

Can anyone help me out?

**What I have right now:**

```
{% if "VenuesController::detailsAction" not in controllerAndActionName %}
```

**What I want to do:**

```
{% if ["VenuesController::detailsAction", "VmsController::indexAction", "DefaultController::headerAction"] not in controllerAndActionName %}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You should post your edit as answer though :) Anyway that is why I said *directly* in `twig`. Extending `twig` is the best way to solve this

Comment: @DarkBee Ok, sure. Thanks for the workaround though still but that looked quite messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of custom Twig extension, I made it possible the following way:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
   return array(
     new \Twig_SimpleFunction('checkMultipleStringValuesContainment', array($this, 'checkMultipleStringValuesContainment'))
   );
}
public function checkMultipleStringValuesContainment($values, $variable) {
    $joinedValues = join($values, "|");
    if (preg_match('~('.$joinedValues.')~', $variable)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then again:

```
{% if checkMultipleStringValuesContainment(["VenuesController::detailsAction", "StaticController::howitworksAction", "StaticController::listyourvenueAction"], controllerAndActionName) == false  %}
```

Comment: slightly unwieldy function name, and you should probably `array_map(function($s) { return preg_quote($s, '~'); }, $values)` before joining, to make the function future proof. unless of course you want to be able to put other regular expressions in your array of values...

Comment: @Jakumi What do you recommend for the function name? Yes, it's not very nice just came to my mind at the time. :)

Comment: highly opinionated, but I would have probably chosen ... `matchAny` or `anyMatch`, or if you negate the logic around a bit even `noneMatch` or `noMatch` or something. even `anyIn` or `noneIn` might be appropriate. But as I said, roll any name you like, because in the end, YOU are the user of your software ;o)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `<string> not in <array>` instead of `<array> not in <string>`:

```
{% if controllerAndActionName not in ["VenuesController::detailsAction", "VmsController::indexAction", "DefaultController::headerAction"] %}
```

Comment: Will only work if `controllerAndActionName` is an exact match of one of the items inside the array though

Comment: Yes, I tried this one but I am not looking for exact match so this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you can do this directly in `twig`, but a workaround should be this

```
{% set bool = true %}
{% for string in ["VenuesController::detailsAction", "VmsController::indexAction", "DefaultController::headerAction"] %}
    {% if string in controllerAndActionName %}
        {% set bool = false %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if bool %}
    Foo
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/p39lul)